# How can I resize these .gif images to fit the height of my Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, image-resizing, animated-gif

Ok, I want to adjust the size of a large list of animated gif files to fit a given size Iframe, in which they will be displayed.
This is my animated .gif file list: (there will be 100+ files in this list)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages=[];
pages[1]="1.gif";
pages[2]="2.gif";
pages[3]="3.gif";
pages[4]="4.gif";
pages[5]="5.gif";
pages[etc]="etc.gif";

</script>
```

(There are functions in the above script, but I edited it out for clarity.)

This is how I call my Iframe:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="" width="1600px" height="897px" hspace="0"     vspace="0" frameborder="2" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

How can I scale ALL of the animated .gif images in a simple way, so each one fits the height of the Iframe?
The .gif files all have different sizes. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use HTML5 canvas and resize them the way you wish. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Comment: I thought of something similar, but I don't use the <img> tag, so I how would use this method?

Comment: why don't you use an image tag to display your animated gif and set the height attibute to 897px?

Comment: Because there will be A LOT of files in that list, so i am looking for a method to control the list var pages=[]